# Python3 Unicode Decode Error Can't Decode Byte

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple server and client messenging program. I found most of how to do it from a tutorial but I can't get arround this error.

The program is meant to start the server, allow a client to connect, display the welcome message and allow the client to type something then the server is to reply with what the client typed.

The program starts the server up and allows me to connect via telnet and displays the welcome message and rite after the error pops up and the program stalls.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

```
import socket,sys
from _thread import *

host = ''
port = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(5)
print('Waiting for a connection.')
def threaded_client(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode('Welcome, type your info\n'))

while True:
    data = conn.recv(2048)
    reply = 'Server output: '+ data.decode('utf-8')
    if not data:
        break
    conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))


conn.close()


while True:

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('connected to: '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))

    start_new_thread(threaded_client,(conn,))
```

Comment: You should test for `data` *before* trying to decode it, not after.